# Workaround Kotlin Code Style restriction in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I would like to set more spaces options for Kotlin. In many other languages there is the "Within" options:

[image]

It seems they are hidden for Kotlin. Is there some way of unlocking them? What I already tried is to put following line in the codeStyle Project.xml:

```
<option name="SPACE_WITHIN_IF_PARENTHESES" value="true" />
```

But Android studio seems to ignore this for Kotlin.

Can anybody give me a hint where in the source code of android-studio these options are restricted?

Answer (score 0):

In the Kotlin YouTrack, there is already a request to add this option (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17741) follow it for updates.